# Problema al imprimir mensaje en debug - Windows

Tags: windows, ensamblador

Estoy realizando una práctica de programación en ensamblador, sobre la herramienta **debug** de Windows para 32 bits.

El ejercicio propuesto es el siguiente:

> Comenzando en la posición de Memoria 012F diseñe un algoritmo que
>   muestre por pantalla el siguiente flujo de caracteres "Este es mi
>   primer programa en el DEBUG“

Nos han dado un ejemplo de como imprimir el típico *"Hola Mundo"* en ensamblador.

[image: Ejemplo Funcional]

Siguiendo este ejemplo, entonces procedí a escribir mi versión dependiendo del ejercicio propuesto:

```
-a
   jmp 120

-e 0102 "Este es mi primer programa en debug" 0a 0d "$"
-a 120
   mov ah,09
   mov dx,0102
   int 21
   int 20
```

Todo este código, lo escribí, basado en el ejemplo funcional. Lo único que le he cambiado es el texto.

Pero al realizar la ejecución del programa *(es decir ejecutar la instrucción -g).*

Obtengo el siguiente resultado:

[image: Ejemplo Fallido]

No entiendo donde se encuentra el problema, he revisado los apuntes, respecto a las instrucciones, pero no entiendo que ha fallado.

Mi pregunta es:

¿Cuál es el error que he cometido, que me lleva a obtener dicho resultado erróneo?

Comment: un consejo para que se te haga la vida de asm mas facil usa el http://assembler8086.blogspot.com/2012/10/ejercicios-en-emu-8086.html emulador que te emula cada paso que hace tu programa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cambia tú código por el siguiente:

```
-a
   jmp 130

-e 0102 "Este es mi primer programa en debug" 0a 0d "$"
-a 130
   mov ah,09
   mov dx,0102
   int 21
   int 20

-g
```

No soy muy bueno con assembler, pero lo que puedo notar es que tu `string` está ubicado en la posición `0102` y tú aplicación empieza en la `0120`.

Ahora bien, al ser

> "Este es mi primer programa en debug"

más largo que

> "Hola mundo"

necesita más posiciones disponibles para ser copiado. Por lo cual, cuando se empieza a escribir la aplicación en la posición `0120`, se está sobrescribiendo el `string` y cuando intenta imprimir no encuentra el fín de la cadena `"$"`.

Entonces lo que estamos haciendo con la ubicación `0130` es iniciar la aplicación un poco mas lejos para que el string tenga el suficiente espacio para  ser copiado.

Comment: Sospechaba que tendria que ver algo con la memoria asignada, igual como en C